# How to transform an angular app which uses keycloak into a mobile app using Cordova?

Tags: android, angular, cordova, keycloak, cordova-plugins

I am currently working on an `angular web application` which uses `keycloak` for authentication. I would like to generate an `android` version using `cordova` technology. But `I'm facing issue of redirection after the user logs in via the keycloak login form.` 
How to redirect the user to the mobile app after authentication ?
Keycloak admin console seems not to accept valid redirect uri like

```
"myapp://"
```

Here is what I did so far :

- Added angular build files into www folder
- Added cordova inappbrowser and whitelist plugins
- Added cordova android platform

Here is my config.xml file:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="com.dom.myapp" version="1.0.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
    <name>MyAPP</name>
    <description>Sample Apache Cordova App</description>
    <author email="dev@cordova.apache.org" href="https://cordova.apache.org">
        Apache Cordova Team
    </author>
    <cdv:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser" />
    <cdv:plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" version="1.0.0" source="npm" />
    <preference name="AndroidLaunchMode" value="singleTask" />
    <preference name="AndroidLaunchMode" value="singleInstance" />
    <preference name="permissions" value="none" />

    <access origin="*"/>
    <content src="index.html" />
    <allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
    
</widget>
```

I got some leads on deeplinks plugin but since I barely have mobile development skills, It's pretty complicated to me. I really need help
Thanks in advance !